# Why does Maven/Eclipse think Java 1.11 is earlier than 1.7?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to start using JDK 11 in a project that was previously developed on JDK 8.

I have the latest Eclipse IDE (Photon).

So I changed this from 1.8 to 1.11 in the project's `pom.xml`:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.11</source>
                    <target>1.11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And now I get the error:

> '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Apparently Maven and/or Eclipse are not interpreting 1.11 correctly.

How to fix?

Comment: For your information, there is no such thing as Java 1.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this then run `Maven -> Update`, ensure Eclipse version is at least `18-09`, and also manually change the JDK level in Eclipse after doing this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Source [here](https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/)

Comment: Partially successful... the 1.7 error is gone but I still can't use JDK 10 features, e.g. error `var cannot be resolved to a type` when trying to declare a `var`

Comment: @AlexR What version of Eclipse Photon do you have? Only  Eclipse 2018-09 does have Java 11 support.

Comment: Looks like I need to upgrade it. I have 2018-06.

Comment: @AlexR I appreciate the fact that you upvoted my answer.

Comment: Just upgrading didn't work either... I had to change the JDK level directly in the Eclipse config (something Maven should have handled for me?)